# One word for "the person from whom we learn to be disciplined"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is one word answer for "the person from whom we learn to be diciplined?"

Comment: Teacher? Is this a cross-word description?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you call a person who motivates or inspires?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115203/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-motivates-or-inspires)

Comment: @RevlisLain Did you read what OP asked? It is not a duplicate at all

Comment: Why do you think there should be one word when you took nine to explain it!

Comment: How about "good example"?

Comment: @yohann v. The discussion on the other page is for words that describe people who inspire others: Luminary and mentor are two mentioned on that page.

Comment: @RevlisLain You are right on *"mentor"* but I don't think *"luminary"* fit with *"disciplined"* since this behaviour control is missing in the post you are linking.

Answer (score 1):

Many types of people fill the role and the first for most people should be their parents. However, all such people are **[Disciplinarian](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=disciplinarian&use1828=on)s** of some sort because that's the essential definition of the word.

The linked Dictionary is [The American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/), which was written by Noah Webster & published in 1828.

Answer (score 0):

COACH - as in someone who trains us to attain a certain level of discipline so that we perform to the best of our abilities

Answer (score 0):

**disciplined** has the [meaning](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disciplined) of

> Showing a controlled form of **behaviour** or way of **working**

And I can't find anything more appropriate to teach at the same time behaviour *and* way of working than the one we call **[master](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/master)**.

> - an owner of a slave or animal
> - a person very skilled or famous in a discipline, as an art or science:
>
> > *one of the great masters of modern art; a Zen master.*

The owner part enphasis the disciplined behaviour you have to learn.

It is an alternative to the common one : *teacher*.

Comment: Teacher and master are fitting, disciplined and its definition are, however, irrelevant to the question of this OP.

Comment: @LittleEva I don't understand why, the OP is asking for one word for “the person from whom we learn to be **disciplined**”.

Comment: Also, I would love to know why I have been downvoted, I could improve my answer then.

Comment: Neither the up-vote, nor the down-vote are from me, Yohann. This OP understands the concept of "disciplined" already, the question being asked builds off that understanding. Whereas, you have expended more time/energy/space (link, direct quotation in block quote, but without citation) on something the OP never asked, than on the terms (**master, teacher**) you've included that *are* adequate responses to OP's question, i.e., "**one word answer for 'the person from whom we learn to be disciplined?**'"

Comment: @LittleEva The explanation of disciplined what to extract two interesting parts which indicate why I'm suggesting those two words. But ok I'll edit to add definition to emphasise the meaning