# I'm looking for a better word than "inspirer"

Tags: single-word-requests

Julian takes up the idea of his ---- Iamblichus.
I'm translating and drawing a blank. It feels like I'm missing something obvious. There's got to be a better word here than 'inspirer'. I don't think 'muse' quite works either. 'Hero' is probably too much.

Comment: Motivator? Inspiration?

Comment: @jmrpink. I wondered about using inspiration for a person, but haven't come up with anything nicer. @ KannE It's the Roman emperor Julian. I actually checked to see if  he could have been mentored by Iamblichus, but the latter died shortly before he was born. Perhaps I've just go to rephrase the whole thing.

Comment: Role model? Idol?

Comment: @jmrpink Role model is nice. I'll need to check if he was a role model and it wasn't just a one off thing.

Comment: _Inspiration_ is a good answer -- people can definitely be an inspiration, as in _August Landmesser should be an inspiration to us all_.

Comment: -1 no research indicated. Please see [How much research is needed?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed) and also the Help Center

Comment: I agree, but I don't like it so much, stylistically, in my specific sentence.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115203/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-motivates-or-inspires   Duplicate

Comment: Thanks Kris. Is there any way to know before posting a question if it's a duplicate? Is there a search tool somewhere on the site?

Comment: @SConroy -- On my system, it's right up there at the top, just to the right of the StackExchange name/logo.

Comment: @Roger. Thanks, found it. Feeling a bit blind now. Mind you it is a little shady and grey :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- Motivator
- Inspiration
- Role model
- Idol
- Exemplar

Here are synonyms for role model, since you liked that suggestion, from Thesaurus.com: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/role%20model?s=t